# WordPress wp-admin showing 504 when performing upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

My WordPress website is sitting behind AWS CloudFront. It caches practically everything including `/wp-admin`. During WordPress upgrade, I get HTTP 504 status.

[image]

Meanwhile, the user facing site continues to work without any issue. And after a while, the admin page recovers on its own. Does anyone face this issue before?